# Como usar un lector de huellas dactilar con react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nestjs

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto(Debe ser web obligatorio sin usar C# u otros lenguajes solo js), en el cual me solicitan registrar huellas de empleados, contratistas y terceros, a su vez también me debe permitir leer la huella y si hace match con alguna ya registrada debo redireccionar a una pantalla donde la persona podrá registrar su inicio de turno, almuerzo, capacitaciones pausas activas etc.

Me piden que al registrar maneje un estándar que ya existe el cual es solicitar la huella cuatro veces.

Estoy perdido y según e buscado necesito crear un servicio para Windows el cual deberá hacer la lectura de la huella ya que el navegador no me permite hacer la lectura directamente.

Alguien tiene conoce alguna guía, libreria, framework o videos que me pueda ayudar o tiene idea de como puedo iniciar este proyecto lo ideal es hacerlo en front con react y en el back con nestjs.

Comment: Hola. Creo que no has hecho un [recorrido por el sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como [hacer una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Para que te puedan ayudar debes exponer un ejemplo claro de lo que estas haciendo, lo que quieres hacer, y los problemas que esta experimentando. Si estas haciendo un curso y el proyecto es para el curso, quiza debas repasarlo, ya que no creo que te soliciten cosas que no hayan dado en el curso. Si es un trabajo, deberias aprender algo más antes de aceptarlos. Empieza tu proyecto y cuando te surjan problemas en él,